# unity 3d: standard material turning dark yellow when changing between scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a cube that collides with an object and after that the scene changes, but as the title says **something affect the material** or idk

in edit mode looks fine:
https://imgur.com/BVdBt0X

but at **runtime** the materiales (**i.e. plane object**) looks a little bit **dark yellow color**:
https://imgur.com/THgS2Up

If you ask for "directional light" parameters, are the same for edit/runtime:

edit mode: https://imgur.com/9uoiCX2

runtime: https://imgur.com/EddXGBV

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its ok for editor, try build for windows and play - everything is going to be ok

Comment: you're right the build works perfect, but it's a version bug???